# How to use React.Suspense loader for JS chunk fetch together with data fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-suspense

We are trying to add loader in our React project (version 18) when we are using lazy-loaded components (during the JS chunk fetch) Suspense fallback loader is displayed afterward the lazy-loaded component fetches its own data in the use effect and another loader is displayed.

Our goal is to unify the both of these loaders, so there is no blinking when the lazy-loaded component renders and begins fetching data.

The problem here is that we have two loaders one after another which are blinking, our target is to make them smooth and to avoid the blinking.

The case is valid only if the network is throttled for example with 3 seconds delay ( that's the only way to reproduce the problem when the connection is very slow, which is important in our case)

Can we use some mechanism to merge them into one loader during the JS chunk fetch and the data fetch?

CodeSandbox Exapmple : https://codesandbox.io/s/suspense-with-react-lazy-forked-u1qguc

React version 18.2.0

App.js

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(import("./Component"));
    }, 3000);
  });
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback={() => <div>Loading...</div>}>
        <OtherComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Component.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function Component(props) {

  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [loading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setUser(json.title);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <div>Loading data....</div>;
  
  return <div>{user}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a codesanbox to show the problem?

Comment: Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspense-with-react-lazy-forked-u1qguc

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about the image loading late you can preload it. Note: You will have to mention the source of the image in your `App` component. (Probably keep it in CONSTANTS somewhere).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = "/loading-icon-red.svg";

  }, []);
```

The img will be pulled in the cache and available, before your new component loads.

**NOTE:** Codesandbox has a garbage collection mechanism, and it is not using the cached image (requested from another component) but on local this will definitely work. Check out the network tab to see the request being actually made.

Comment: The idea here is to combine the first loader and get rid of the 2nd one. Currently if you get rid of the 2nd loader, the component stays empty until the data is fetched. Currently not seen in the example is the slight blink between the two loaders, when we throttle the network in our project the blink is a lot more visible.